# Can't find class inside class

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this html structure

```
<div class="parent">
     <span class="children">This is children text</span>
     <br>
     <span>another text</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
     <span class="children">This is children text</span>
     <br>
     <span>another text</span>
</div>
```

And I try to parse it with puppeteer

```
result.parents = []
let parents = await page.$$('.parent')
for (let i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {
   let chd = await parents[i].$eval('.children', ele => ele.innerText)
   result.parents.push(chd)
}
```

That code gives an error result

`Could not resolve the browser instance =>  Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector ".children"`

why?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue with this test script. Maybe you miss some details in the question?

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>

      <div class="parent">
           <span class="children">This is children text</span>
           <br>
           <span>another text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="parent">
           <span class="children">This is children text</span>
           <br>
           <span>another text</span>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const result = {};
  result.parents = [];
  const parents = await page.$$('.parent');
  for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
     const chd = await parents[i].$eval('.children', ele => ele.innerText);
     result.parents.push(chd);
  }

  console.log(result);
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Output:

```
{ parents: [ 'This is children text', 'This is children text' ] }
```